# Strange DNS behaviour over VPN

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, vpn

We have a small branch with few computers with few computers connected via the Internet to our central building. We don't use site-to-site, but dial-in to the Cisco router (we use ShrewSoft as a client and pull network configuration from the RADIUS server).

Everything was working just fine, but our tel-co was messing around with something (not clear what) as they had promised. Yesterday I got a call from the branch and they said they could browse the Internet, but can't access our internal web servers. I started investigating and it turned out the VPN settings were all messed up, OK fixed that.

The most interesting part is the DNS stuff. After I restored the VPN, I connected using RDP to their computer and tried pinging our `Internal DNS server (192.168.1.31)` and `Google's DNS (8.8.8.8)`. That worked fine. I then tried `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` - works fine. Then `nslookup www.google.com 192.168.1.31` - that works fine! BUT trying to resolve any of our internal addresses fails. We have a few of DNS servers and all of them fail. Looks like the reply never gets back. From internal network it works fine. But how does that happen: `nslookup` resolves our dns server's FQDN using reverse lookup?? It doesn't have anything to do with firewalls, right? Reverse lookup gets a reply. Help me please, in which direction should I look?

[image: Diagram]

PS. To the left of the cloud is our central building, to the right - branch.

PPS. I've written the needed records to the `hosts` file just as a temporary workaround so they could do their job.

PPPS. Cannot really check with other computers in branch as they don't use VPN and the employees there are in their 60s so they don't understand a thing and can do only very simple things.

Comment: Stupid question, but it doesn't actually state this. Are you sure that your clients DHCP servers on the remote side are providing them with the correct internet DNS servers when they get their DHCP addresses?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct. I tried nslookup with different servers... so it's not about addresses

Comment: "From internal network it works fine." can you clarify what you mean?  Does a normal nslookup work when you are on the central building network and not from a branch PC over the VPN when you do `nslookup internalservername.internaldomain.com 192.168.1.31`?  But doing `nslookup www.google.com 192.168.1.31` does work on the branch PC?

Comment: Yes nslookup works absolutely fine when at central building. But at the branch site you can only receive non-authoritative replies (but not our internal network records). Also you do get back replies from reverse lookups at branch